# Mongo: How to count how many values in fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have collection

```js
[
    {
        data: {
            height: 1,
            width:  2
        }
    },{
        data: {
            height: 3,
            width:  2
        }
    },{
        data: {
            height: 3,
            width:  1
        }
    }
]
```

How can I count how many 1's and 3's in data.height and 1's and 2's in data.width? Basically I need result like

```js
{
    data: {
        haight: {
            "1": 1,
            "3": 2
        },
        width:  {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for now I got what I need with mapReduce and it's "scope" parameter

```js
db.myCollection.mapReduce(
    function(){
        if( this.data.height in res.data.height === false ) res.data.height[this.data.height] = 0;
        if( this.data.width in res.data.width === false ) res.data.width[this.data.width] = 0;

        res.data.height[this.data.height]++;
        res.data.width[this.data.width]++;

        emit('id', 1);
    },
    function(){
        return res;
    },
    {
        out: {inline: 1},
        scope: {
            res: {
                data:{
                    height: {},
                    width:  {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I count how many 1's and 3's in data.height and 1's and 2's in data.width?

It's possible to aggregate each value individually (as show in other answers). Alternatively, you can aggregate both values with a single command:

```js
db.test.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$data.height", width: {$push: "$data.width"}, heightCount: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$project: {height: {id: "$_id", count: "$heightCount"}, width: 1}},
    {$unwind: "$width"},
    {$group: {_id: "$width", widthCount: {$sum: 1}, height: {$addToSet: "$height"}}},
    {$unwind: "$height"},
    {$group: {_id: null, width: {$addToSet: {id: "$_id", count: "$widthCount"}}, height: {$addToSet: "$height"}}})
```

> How can I count how many **1's and 3's in data.height and 1's and 2's** in data.width?

If you only want to aggregate *1's and 3's in data.height and 1's and 2's in data.width*, then you can put the following command at the beginning of the pipeline:

```js
{$match: {$and: [{$or: [{"data.width": 1}, {"data.width": 2}]}, {$or: [{"data.height": 1}, {"data.height": 3}]}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think aggregation will be faster than mapReduce, but mapReduce is more understandable